# How to extract parts of this array - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to print part of this array, basically all the URLS [href] with "ProviderRedirect.ashx" basically [0] to [infinite]

```
Array

(
    [name] => HC Redirect
    [count] => 66
    [frequency] => Daily
    [version] => 14
    [newdata] => 1
    [lastrunstatus] => partial
    [thisversionstatus] => success
    [nextrun] => Sun Jan 17 2016 14:03:08 GMT+0000 (UTC)
    [thisversionrun] => Sat Jan 16 2016 14:03:08 GMT+0000 (UTC)
    [results] => Array

    (
        [collection1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Hotel Search] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.domain.com/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.6359329.272723160.5179.GBP.1729297590&saving=410&source=32-0
                                [text] => View Deal
                            )

                        [index] => 1
                        [url] => https://www.domain.com/Hotels/Search?destination=place:London&checkin=2016-09-02&checkout=2016-09-09&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=EN¤cyCode=GBP&pageSize=50
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Hotel Search] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.domain.com/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.21199849.272723130.457.GBP.753573779&source=32-0
                                [text] => View Deal
                            )

                        [index] => 2
                        [url] => https://www.domain.com/Hotels/Search?destination=place:London&checkin=2016-09-02&checkout=2016-09-09&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=EN¤cyCode=GBP&pageSize=50
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [Hotel Search] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.domain.com/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.23906211.272723157.1326.GBP.2008823249&source=32-0
                                [text] => View Deal
                            )

                        [index] => 3
                        [url] => https://www.domain.com/Hotels/Search?destination=place:London&checkin=2016-09-02&checkout=2016-09-09&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=EN¤cyCode=GBP&pageSize=50
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [Hotel Search] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.domain.com/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.5242811.272723157.3854.GBP.1642352834&source=32-0
                                [text] => View Deal
                            )

                        [index] => 4
                        [url] => https://www.domain.com/Hotels/Search?destination=place:London&checkin=2016-09-02&checkout=2016-09-09&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=EN¤cyCode=GBP&pageSize=50
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [Hotel Search] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.domain.com/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.675524.272723160.1457.GBP.2121712597&saving=18&source=32-0
                                [text] => View Deal
                            )

                        [index] => 5
                        [url] => https://www.domain.com/Hotels/Search?destination=place:London&checkin=2016-09-02&checkout=2016-09-09&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=EN¤cyCode=GBP&pageSize=50
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [Hotel Search] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.domain.com/ProviderRedirect.ashx?key=0.5743724.272723155.847.GBP.1001086600&source=32-0
                                [text] => View Deal
                            )

                        [index] => 6
                        [url] => https://www.domain.com/Hotels/Search?destination=place:London&checkin=2016-09-02&checkout=2016-09-09&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&languageCode=EN¤cyCode=GBP&pageSize=50
                    )

                [6] => Array
```

Comment: *Ok. Wow*. But, Dear Please Show Us Your Code, Which You Tried.

Comment: var_dump($page[9][0][0][0][0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `array_walk_recursive()` function or write your own function to recursively traverse the array and print all urls.

Suppose `$arr` is your array.

**Method(1):**

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item, $key) {
    if ($key == "href") {
        echo $item . "<br />";
    }
});
```

**Method(2):**

```
function process_array($array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            process_array($value);
        }else{
            if($key == "href"){
                echo $value . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}

process_array($arr);
```

Comment: @h-y-b-r-i-d Glad I could help. Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. :)

Comment: Thanks again, For bonus points how would I echo a random url from the list ?

Comment: @h-y-b-r-i-d If you want to print a random url from the array then do this: `$arrayLength = count($arr['results']['collection1']); $random_url = $arr['results']['collection1'][rand(0, $arrayLength - 1)]['Hotel Search']['href'];`. And echo `$random_url`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $items = array(
            'results' => array(
                'collection1'=> array(
                    array(
                        'hotel_search'=>array(
                            'href'=>'value'
                        ),
                        'index'=>'value'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'hotel_search'=>array(
                            'href'=>'value'
                        ),
                        'index'=>'value'
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $collection1 = $items['results']['collection1'];

        foreach($collection1 as $collection) {
             printf("%s", $collection['hotel_search']['href']);
        }
```

You would need to loop over the results array though to avoid hardcoding

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is print the values, array_walk_recursive would do the job:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) {
    if ('href' === $key) {
        echo "$item\n";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that thows a 500 error.

<?php
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$page = json_decode($response, TRUE);
array_walk_recursive($page, function($item, $key) {
    if ('href' === $key) {
        echo "$item\n";
    }
}
?>

Comment: Forgot the ending parenthesis/semicolon. Answer updated.